# How do I make $_POST not resubmit form information on page refresh

Tags: php, html, post

I have a button that acts as a submit:

```
<button  id='bet_horse' name='bet_horse' type="submit" class='btn btn-default bet_btn' >
     Submit This Info    
</button>
```

And a way for the post to be handled:

```
if ($_POST) {
$countInserts = 0;
if (isset($_POST['bet_horse'])) {
    if ($countInserts < 1) {
        $bs->insertbet_betslip(
            'horse',
            $current_user2->ID, 
            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nameMarket']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nameType']), 
            $_POST['p_name'], 0, 
            $_POST['odds'], 
            $_POST['bettilltime'], 
            $_POST['bettilldate'], 
            date("H:i:s", time()),
            date("Y-m-d"),
            is_user_logged_in() ? true : false
        );
    }
//header("Location: /"); //This cannot be done becaause headers are already sent.
}
```

But after this I need to be able to stop the post from posting, the only ways I found of doing this is shown in the comment in the code, however I could not do this because of a lot of background WordPress processes, another way I thought to do it was with the `if ($countInserts < 1 ) {  }`, but again didn't work, I have seacrhed for an answer but have been unsucessful, can anybody help?

Comment: You could use exit() to stop processing

Comment: Would that not mean the form would have to be resent then to keep the page active and live?

Comment: What does that mean exactly, *"stop the post from posting"*?!

Comment: @deceze, it means that when the page is refreshed, it asks you to "confirm form resubmission" and re-sends the post back to the server, what I want to happen is for the post NOT to go back to the server and be stopped where it is.

Comment: @swiftie821 That is a function of the browser, it's not something you can change.

Comment: @Styphon, if you look at a site like Facebook, you permernantly send information to the server, I am usure of this is post or not, but when you refesh the page you are not asked to resubmit the form, so what would be the best "work around" for avoiding this as I only want one of the information desired sent back?

Comment: @swiftie821 Use Ajax to submit the form.

Comment: @Styphon, this would be done on a button click, not a submit, is that correct?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294378/how-could-prevent-refresh-page-problem-while-submitting-form/5294386#5294386

Comment: You can do it on either. If you use jQuery you can intercept either the button click or the form submit. I'd recommend intercepting the form submit.

Comment: @Styphon, may I ask why you would intercept the submit over a button click? (Pure intrigue on another programmers opinion)

Comment: Because clicking a button is not the only way to submit a form. You can do it with the enter button as well. If you intercept the button click rather than the form submit you lose that functionality.

Comment: @Styphon, Thank you for that, I will do my best to get that in place, thank you again.

Comment: Just to make that clear: I'm pretty sure you're looking for a **POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern**. See aforelinked duplicate. This is a super common technique, no need to invent anything via Javascript.

Comment: @deceze no, that's not what the OP is after. For example, you submit a search form to a page. Then you refresh the page, the browser asks you to resubmit the data again. That's what the OP wants to stop.

Comment: @Styphon Still: POST/REDIRECT/GET. A search form shouldn't be submitted via POST to begin with, or at least be converted into a GET request from there using P/R/G.

Comment: @deceze It's not POST/REDIRECT/GET, there is no redirect. The search form was an example (a bad one) just to illustrate what the user is after. If you wanted the posted data to be GET, the OP could just change the forms method.

Comment: @Styphon There is not redirect, **but there should be one**. The point of P/R/G is precisely to prevent re-POSTing by refreshing.

Comment: @deceze right, sorry, got there in the end hehe.

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

```
wp_redirect( $location, $status );
exit;
```

For example:

```
wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;
```

Or if Headers was submitted You can use JavaScript:

```
echo '<script>window.location = "/"</script>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little unclear, but if you want to stop the POSTED data being resubmitted with a page reload, or page refresh then try reading this article:

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html

with thanks to Fred-ii- for the original link!

In summary, you need to set a token id value from the $_SESSION into the form, and then check that the token id value given in the $_POST data matches the SESSION data. Once the form is submitted the first time you can then delete the $_SESSION token id and only commit changes if the $_SESSION id == $_POST id.

Comment: That will allow you to identify if it's been reposted, but it doesn't stop it from being reposted.

Comment: If you read the article it does exactly that, it stops refreshing the destination page from resubmitting the data because once the data has been submitted the SESSION value is deleted, so that the posted form data can never then equal the session value (As it's unset)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said. However it doesn't stop the browser from asking you to refresh the page and resubmit the data.

Comment: the data is resubmitted to the page, but the data is not acted upon within the PHP code (as it's already been submitted), so the data is ignored. I think this is what the  OP is looking for.

Comment: I don't think it is, from his comments the OP doesn't even want the data to be resubmitted to the page.

Comment: yes....... my answers shows how to prevent the data being ***re***submitted to the page and being used. .

Comment: I want the information to be gone after the first submit, the form should not even know that it ever existed, @Styphon hit the nail on the head there

Comment: ok :) It may be helpful to me (and others) to edit and clarify what you actually want in the question, but glad it's solved :)