# What is standard practice when dealing with an HTML POST form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, standards

I've been working on this site and I know I can make a form but when I submit the form the php page shows up, now if I try to refresh the page I get this

[image]

which makes me think that I shouldn't be showing my PHP pages and there is a way to do all of the PHP work behind the scenes.

So what I'm asking if is that correct that I should show HTML/JavaScript pages and do PHP behind the scenes? And also how do you do PHP behind the scenes without showing the PHP page?

Comment: PHP is never shown on the client side as it is a server side script. You're not doing anything wrong. If you hit refresh after submitting a form, it's normal for your browser to confirm that you want to resubmit the form.

Comment: can you show me the existing question, because ive been looking and cant find the answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294378/how-could-prevent-refresh-page-problem-while-submitting-form its shown at top

Comment: You have a `post` form (suitable for an operation that does a write or some other operation that must not be repeated) and you need to do a redirect after you have finished it (except in error conditions where a redirect would lose user input). Use `header('Location: /your/form.php'); exit();` to go back to the same page in a new `get` request.